# Drupal: привязать класс css к markup

Tags: drupal, php

В форме создаётся элемент с типом markup:

```
if (variable_get('uc_continue_shopping_type', 'link') == 'link') {
      $form['continue_shopping'] = array(
        '#value' => l($cs_text, uc_cart_continue_shopping_url()),
      );
    }
```

В итоге из этого получается ссылка.
Для оформления этой ссылки надо прикрутить класс. Пробовал так:

```
$form['continue_shopping']['#attributes'] = array('class'=>'link-cs');
```

Не помогло. Хардкодом не вариант: ссылка динамическая.
Как это сделать средствами api?

**Upd:** как написано [здесь](http://api.drupal.ru/api/file/developer/topics/forms_api_reference.html/6#markup), "`этот элемент не обертывается в html-теги вообще`". Оттого и проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[l | Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/6)

```
$attributes = array('class'=>'link-cs');

$options = array('attributes'=>$attributes);

$form['continue_shopping'] = array(
        '#value' => l($cs_text, uc_cart_continue_shopping_url(),$options),
      );
//Можете схлопнуть в одну строку. Разбил для наглядности.
```

P.S. у [markup](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#markup)  НЕТ аттрибутов.